# Failed to login even credentials are exactly right in laravel login

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I made a login form, while I used to enter credentials, my email and password are absolutely correct, but this code shown me an error, that I defined in else condition. please help me to find my mistake.

**loginstudent.blade.php  (login form)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <form action="{{route('matchlogin')}}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <div class="container">
                <label for="uname"><b>Email</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required/> <br/>

                <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pwd" required/> <br/>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
    </table>
</div>
@if(\Session::has('notmatch'))
<div class="container">
    <h2> {{\Session::get('notmatch')}} </h2>
</div>
@endif
</body>
</html>
```

**studentcontroller.php (controller function)**

```
public function matchlogin(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->pwd;

    if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password))) {
        return "success";
    } else {
        $request->session()->flash('notmatch', 'Email & password not match');
        return redirect(route('loginstudent'));
    }
}
```

**web.php (Routes)**

```
Route::get('/loginstudent','studentcontroller@login')->name('loginstudent');
Route::post('/checklogin','studentcontroller@matchlogin')->name('matchlogin');
```

Comment: Please mention the error you got in your question

Answer (score 1):

How did you save your password? Is it hashed and then saved? Because `Auth::attempt` matches the hashed pattern. If your password is saved in simple text or in some other encryption form, it won't work and will give mismatch.

Thanks

Comment: It is in simple text, but my problem is solved Auth::attempt by default check into users table, my table is different.